# "Don't sprink water on others" or "Don't sprink water on other people"

Tags: word-usage

I took my son to the swimming pool. He sprink water on other people.

> Don't sprink water on others.
>
> Don't sprink water on other people.

Could *others* be used instead of *other people*? Can they have the same meaning?

Comment: There is no word ***sprink*** in English. You're obviously thinking of ***sprinkle***, but idiomatically the verb for your context would almost always be ***splash*** anyway.

Comment: You can indeed use _others_ to mean _other people_, particularly in a prepositional phrase staring with _on_.

Comment: Perhaps the OP has been reading the OED ("**sprink**: *obs.* exc. *dial*. to sprinkle").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Umm, I am not familiar with any English word "sprink". Where did you hear this?

I'd guess you heard "sprinkle" or maybe "splash".

To "sprinkle" is to pour a small amount of a liquid as drops. Like if you got some water on your hands and then flicked your fingers, you would sprinkle water. Or if you had a hose and you used it in a way that you didn't drop much water on any given place, like spray it up into the air.

To "splash" is to push against water to throw some of it in the air. Like take your open hand and slap the water in a way that makes the water hit people or objects.

Your basic sentence is valid grammar. "Don't sprinkle water on people." "Don't sprinkle water on others." "Don't splash water on people." Etc.